# Script doesn't work in WebView for react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

I trying to add helpcrunch chat in my mobile app via WebView. For it I need to add a few scripts in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(w,d){
  w.HelpCrunch=function(){w.HelpCrunch.q.push(arguments)};w.HelpCrunch.q=[];
  function r(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.async=1;s.type='text/javascript';s.src='https://widget.helpcrunch.com/';(d.body||d.head).appendChild(s);}
  if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',r)}else{w.addEventListener('load',r,false)}
})(window, document)
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  HelpCrunch('init', 'app', {
    applicationId: 2,
    applicationSecret: 'appKEY'
  })

  HelpCrunch('showChatWidget');
</script>
```

In IOS all work well. But on android, this script doesn't work.

Code with my WebView:

```
<WebView
          injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_SCRIPTS}
          onMessage={this.onMessage}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          source={{ html: `<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport"
                  content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
       <body>
        <h1 id="about">regnergioi</h1>
        </body>
      </html>` }}
          style={{ marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 10, height: 400 }}
          renderError={(a) => this.handleError(a)}
          onError={(a) => this.handleError(a)}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help with the WebView problem but I can suggest a unofficial HelpCrunch library for React Native.
It's a bit old but I think it will work fine after updating the SDK versions to latest for both platforms

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-helpcrunch

Latest versions:

- Android: 3.1.4 [update here](https://github.com/KyteApp/react-native-helpcrunch/blob/272969c20a09998afef9828b1236b60ffa4be41d/android/build.gradle#L61)
- iOS: 3.3.6 [update here](https://github.com/KyteApp/react-native-helpcrunch/blob/272969c20a09998afef9828b1236b60ffa4be41d/react-native-helpcrunch.podspec#L22)